# How to calculate joint probability density function?

Tags: probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to rationalize Maximum likelihood estimation of paramaters of continuous variables to myself.

I can almost accept that in the case of continuous variables we use probability density as a "proxy" of probabilities (since the actual probabilities of the observations would be 0)

But can we obtain a joint density function just by multiplying the original density functions?

I can't seem to find such a rule anywhere....

Comment: In the case of independence: yes.

Comment: Right, is there an official rule you can link to? Would make me feel better :)